# Get a multi dimensional array out of a txt file row

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have this text file which contains `5` rows that relate to the map of my game.
I want to read one of these text lines and convert them to a 2D array of `bool`s.
I have succeeded in reading the other lines, but on the last line, which is formatted something like this (original line is much longer):

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

But couldn't figure out a good efficient way to convert it to a 2D `bool` array.

Have tried this loop (which isn't working because of the formatting of my map I believe):

```
for (int y = 0; y < this->map_height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < this->map_width; x++)
    {
        char temp;
        mapFile >> temp;
        std::cout << temp;
        if (temp == '0')
            this->collisions[x][y] = false;
        else if (temp == '2')
            this->collisions[x][y] = true;
    }
}
```

But since I have `,` in my formatting I encounter other problems.
How can I read that line and convert into a 2D dimensional array efficiently ?

Comment: Is you questioned narrowed down to how to deal with `','`?

Comment: @jafar I figured a way to deal with the 
` ','` its just that it seems like there is a better way of doing it. The way im refering to is as Joachim stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the whole line into a string, put the string into a `std::istringstream` object, tokenize (using `std::getline` with `','` as separator) the numbers (as *numbers* and not as characters) in a loop, and put the number in the correct position in the matrix.

That's *one* way to do it.

Comment: That's what I figured, but it seems like there is a better way of doing it.
Any ideas?

Comment: @user1885604 There are other ways, but this is, I think, the simplest. The problem is with the commas, if there weren't commas it could be so much simpler. :)

Comment: Agreed. I'm also interested in how you would turn the line into the 2d array if you don't mind me asking you and if it's not much to bother you with :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a followup to Joachim Pileborg answer. You can directly use the comma (`','`) delimiter in `std::getline` to split input file on commas, and then use an `istringstream` or simply an `strtol` to parse the individuals elements as integers. Something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(ival)/sizeof(ival[0]); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<sizeof(ival[0])/sizeof(ival[0][0]); j++) {
        std::getline(in, tok, ',');
        ival[i][j] = strtol(tok.c_str(), NULL, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against changing the input file, the easiest way would be to just remove all the (,)'s from the input.  This would allow you to use your code mostly unchanged.  Else you would need to use istringstream as mentioned previously.  Or read as a string and remove each , then convert to integer